# .htaccess issue: trailing slash added, but not working for subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have found a well working .htaccess code on the internet that removed the .html extension and adds a trailing slash at the end of the URL.

However, when I link to a site in a subdirectory, it does not work, the subdirectory automatically gets erased in the URL, so the page is not loaded.

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I also have this same .htaccess in said subdirectory, which I'm not sure if that is the right way to do this.

I may need to add that I'm new to coding altogether, I have just started putting together an update of my website mostly by extensive google searches on coding, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this issue?

Edit: for clarification I may add that the subdirectory I'm talking about is part of the same website, so some parts of it I would like to keep in a subdirectory just for keeping things organized.

Answer (score 0):

> I also have this same .htaccess in said subdirectory, which I'm not sure if that is the right way to do this.

Well, it really depends on your URL structure and how many path segments you have. The "well working" `.htaccess` code you posted only works on single path segments, ie. files in the document root.

However, you should not need to repeat this `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory. In fact, these directives are not correct if used in a subdirectory - which is probably why your subdirectory is being "erased". The last line (`RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`) will remove the subdirectory from the redirected request when used inside the subdirectory.

Try instead:

1. Remove the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory.
2. Change the following directive:

   > ```
   > RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
   > ```

   To read:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html
   ```

   In order to target any directory level. Otherwise, it is limited to targetting files in the document root only.